# XStream corrupting values on load and save

Tags: java, xml, xstream

My team has recently inherited a codebase that utilizes XStream 1.4.7 to load and save XML for configuration settings which then de-/serializes them from/to custom POCOs. The problem that we're having is that some of the values are getting corrupted during reads or writes. It isn't consistently occurring either which makes it that much more unusual. In most cases, it works perfectly fine with the exact same XML and the exact same POCOs.

A very simplified example (I can't post the exact code and it's quite a bit more complex so I'm going for an easy way to explain what we're seeing) is given the XML:

```
  <monitor>
    <autostart>true</autostart>
    <name>MYVALUE</name>
  </monitor>
```

Mapped to a POCO:

```
public class MonitorEntry {
  public Boolean autostart;
  public String name;
}
```

Loaded with XStream:

```
XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xStream.alias("Monitor", MonitorEntry.class);
Monitor monitor = (Monitor)xStream.fromXML(myFile);
```

The value of `name` in the `Monitor` object is read in as `arVALUE` instead of `MYVALUE`. The garbage characters at the beginning are what throws things off. Even more strangely, if we change the value of the `<autostart>` element to `false` then the XML is mapped correctly and the garbage characters do not appear.

To add to the mystery, on our end we're only seeing the corruption on *loading* XML to objects, but on one particular customer system they are seeing corruption only when actually *saving* the XML from objects. In this case, it's exactly the opposite of the above scenario. Given the same POCO with `name` set to `MYVALUE`, the actual XML written to the XML file becomes:

```
  <monitor>
    <autostart>true</autostart>
    <name>arVALUE</name>
  </monitor>
```

Now for a string value such as `name` it isn't much of a functional issue as it's just a name that is then just spelled wrong but where this becomes a problem is when mapping the XML value to, for example, an `enum` and the mapping can't find the enum value.

An example being if there is an enum:

```
public enum Type { VALUE1, VALUE2 };
```

And the POCO is:

```
public class MonitorEntry {
  public Boolean autostart;
  public String name;
  public Type type;
}
```

With the XML:

```
  <monitor>
    <autostart>true</autostart>
    <name>MYNAME</name>
    <type>VALUE2</type>
  </monitor>
```

But the XML value is being read by XStream as `erLUE2` then the XStream mapping won't be able to match the correct enum value and throws an exception such as:

```
No enum const class com.sample.MonitorEntry$Type.erLUE2
```

We tried updating to XStream 1.4.8 just to see if perhaps something had been fixed but the behavior persists. The codebase is set to compile to Java 1.6 but we've tried 1.6, 7, and 8 as runtimes just to see if it was a runtime bug or something else environmental.

Has anyone else seen similar issues or have any suggestions on what might cause this? I can further update my post to include more detail if necessary. We've used XStream quite a bit before but never had issues.

Edit: We are not currently using any custom converters in this codebase, only the built-in XStream converters.

Comment: What if you try a different driver such as `StaxDriver` to make it use a different XML parsing API? Are you using any custom converters anywhere?

Comment: I'll update my original post also but we don't have any custom converters in this codebase. We haven't tried an alternate driver yet but that's a good point, I'll have to put that on the list of things to try.

Comment: Using the `StaxDriver` ends up causing a NPE when it tries parsing the XML. The stacktrace is not helpful either.